# Is if(pointerVar) the same as if(pointerVar!=NULL)?

Tags: c++, pointers

Simple question:

Is `if (pointerVar)` the same as `if (pointerVar!=NULL)`?

Also, is `if (!pointerVar)` the same as `if (pointerVar==NULL)`?

Give me your most technically correct/pedantic answer. The two statements seem and make sense to operate the same. Is there anything wrong with the former though (besides its slightly lower readability)?

Comment: Are we to assume `pointerVar` is an in-scope variable that has a pointer type? And is `NULL` defined from `<cstddef>`? What is the token `NULLL`? Is your `if`-statement in a function block? We can't be pedant unless you're pedant back.

Comment: I'd argue against *"lower readability of the former"* if it's obvious from the contect that `pointerVar` is a pointer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the most pedantic answer, here's the relevant sections of the spec.

First, here's how `if` statements work, from §6.4.4:

> The value of a condition that is an initialized declaration in a statement other than a switch statement is the value of the declared variable **implicitly converted to type `bool`**. If that conversion is ill-formed, the program is ill-formed.

"But how are pointers converted to `bool`s?" you may ask.  Well, here's §4.12.1: :-)

> An rvalue of arithmetic, enumeration, **pointer**, or pointer to member type can be converted to an rvalue of type bool. A zero value, **null pointer value**, or null member pointer value is converted to false; any other value is converted to true.

So this means that the statement

```
if (ptr)
```

is equivalent to

```
if ((bool) ptr)
```

which is in turn equivalent to

```
if (ptr == NULL)
```

But what about

```
if (!ptr)
```

Well, the C++ spec, §5.3.1.8, says that

> The operand of the logical negation operator ! is implicitly converted to `bool` (clause 4); its value is `true` if the converted operand is `false` and `false` otherwise. The type of the result is `bool`.

So this means that

```
if (!ptr)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (!(bool)ptr)
```

which is in turn equivalent to

```
if (!(ptr == NULL))
```

which is finally equivalent to

```
if (ptr != NULL)
```

Whew!  That was a fun search to do.  Hope this answers your question!

Of course, there is more to this story.  `NULL` is not part of the C++ language; it's a macro in `<cstddef>` defined as

```
#define NULL 0
```

This works because the C++ standard defines the null pointer in §4.10.1 as

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of **integer type that evaluates to zero**. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of pointer to object or pointer to function type

So to be more correct, I should have been using the numeric literal 0 in the above examples.  However, if you have `<cstddef>` included, then this works out to the same code after preprocessing.

Comment: `if ((bool) ptr)` doesn't follow from §6.4.4, since that's an explicit conversion.

Comment: I'm all in favor of pedantry, but this might be a bit too pedantic.  :-O

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: I don't think it's pedantic enough, there's no mention of what `NULL` might be or what you need to include to get a definition of `NULL`. Is `NULL` even a null pointer value? This is probably the most important _practical_ point.

Comment: @Charles Bailey- NULL is `#define`d to be 0 in `<cstddef>`.  The null pointer is an rvalue with integer value 0.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I know, that belongs in this answer, doesn't it?

Comment: @Charles Bailey- Perhaps, but that's just too pedantic, even for me.  And I'm usually pretty pedantic!

Comment: @templatetypedef: Too pedantic? It has real repercussions. You need to provide a definition of `NULL` before you can use it. To me it's an important difference between the two conditions.

Comment: @Charles Bailey- You do have a valid point.  I'll update the post.  Thanks for being understanding.

Comment: Thanks, very good and precise answer. The reason I was being pedantic is because I use the former expressions a lot and I just needed to be sure I wasn't invoked any evil UB.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `pointerVar` is a raw pointer, then yes. Otherwise, it depends, though usually it is still practically the same for smart pointers.

There is certainly nothing wrong with the first version, in fact, many experienced C++ programmers would consider it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ `NULL` expands to either `0` or `0L`. So `if (pointerVar)` the same as `if (pointerVar!=NULL)` and  `if (!pointerVar)` is the same as `if (pointerVar==NULLL)`.

Comment: It expands to any null pointer constant (integral constant expression with the value zero), so it could expand to `(1 - 1)`, etc.

Comment: It may even expand to `false`, so `ptr != NULL` would expand to `ptr != false`

Comment: @MSalters: I'm not convinced that it can (conformingly) evaluate to `false`. Although `false` converts to the value `0` when converted to an integer type (other than `bool`), I don't believe the standard ever states that `false` is zero and `NULL` must be an integer constant expression that evaluates directly to zero.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: `bool` is an integral type, and `false` is a constant of type `bool`. It's therefore an Integral Constant Expression per 5.19 (note: not _integer_ constant expression) that _evaluates_ to zero. This is similar to `0L`, another non-`int` that evaluates to zero. Since "evaluating to zero" is all that's needed, `false` is a valid null pointer constant.

Comment: @MSalters: My point is that `false` isn't zero. It just converts to zero when converted to any other integer type. I agree that `bool` is an integer type. See 4.7/4 and 4.12. It is always specified that `false` is _converted_ to zero and zero is _converted_ to false.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: that's why I pointed out that a "null pointer constant" is anything that **evaluates to** zero.

Comment: @MSalters: OK, I'm not following you; I thought you were saying that `false` was a valid definition for `NULL`?

Comment: @Charles Bailey: It is. `NULL` must expand to a valid null pointer constant. Since `false` is a valid null pointer constant, `NULL` may expand to `false`.

Comment: @MSalters: No, strictly speaking `false` isn't a valid null pointer constant because the expression `false` has type `bool` and evaluates to false. It requires a conversion to some other integral type to become a value of zero.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are right. Remember that the condition is false if it returns zero value, it is true otherwise. In above expressions when pointerVal = NULL, (NULL is zero internally), `if(pointerVal)`  will return false. Reverse is true for `if(!pointerVal)` as we are negating the condition.
Both expressions are valid and common practice.