# Is if(!x) the same as if(x!=null)

Tags: groovy, boolean-expression

I know his is sort of a duplicate of [Is if(pointerVar) the same as if(pointerVar!=NULL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966002/is-ifpointervar-the-same-as-ifpointervar-null), but I have to ask anyway.

In Groovy, we have the following:

```
def x = someMethod()
if( !x ) {
   // do good stuff
}
```

This is just a standard `null` check, ie `(x != null)`, right?

Comment: What language are you asking about? They are all different.

Comment: I don't think the duplicate link is relevant, because it only covers C++, and this question is primarily about Groovy, with reference to C/C++/Perl/Ruby

Comment: For full info about `if (! x)`, read about [Groovy Truth](http://www.groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth). Section 5.8 "Object References" (not pointers) answers your question: *Yes, it's a null check.* --- As for Java: **No**, it's not the same, because `if (! x)` is *invalid* for anything other than `x` being a boolean value.

Comment: Joe: Asking the same question for different languages is [perfectly acceptable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272888/176646), although in general you should only ask about one language per question. I would remove the bit about Java and clarify that you're asking about Groovy, not Perl, C++, Ruby, etc. I don't use Groovy but this is clearly not a duplicate of that C++ question, @πάντα ῥεῖ (it may well be a dupe of some other question though).

Comment: Updated question to remove mention of other languages. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `if` in groovy calls the underlying `asBoolean()` method. This is known as [Groovy truth](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-tell-groovy-truth.html).

Empty lists, empty strings, empty maps, null, `0`, are all falsy values:

```
if ([:]) {
    assert false
}

if (null) {
    assert false
}

if ("") {
    assert false
}

if (0) {
    assert false
}

assert null.asBoolean() == false

assert 1.asBoolean()
```

You can also write `asBoolean` in your own classes.